# DataGrip - Show Query Elapsed Time - UI Configuration

Tags: datagrip

**DataGrip Build: 2018.1.5

Build #DB-181.5281.40 - June 19, 2018

Redshift SQL Project**

Hi,

Looking at a [feature request post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3063) on JetBrains' website, I see that an elapsed query running timer was added to DataGrip in 2017. While I see this elapsed time when a query completes successfully, nothing is shown when a query is manually aborted, or during the query's execution (such as a timer that counts up in seconds as the query is being run).

Am I missing an option in the UI settings to enable this, or are there no features that exist to show this information? The current bottom bar of the UI looks like this:

[image]

Below is an example pulled from a different client (It is showing a stuck query, with a very long runtime):

[image: example elapsed time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature like this (live-timer), and there is a ticket for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-269

Comment: That's excellent that there is a feature request open for the live-timer aspect! Do you know if the running time up until a query is manually cancelled by the user is displayed/logged anywhere?

Comment: In 2018.2 EAP there is a new feature called SQL Log. https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/06/21/datagrip-2018-2-eap-is-open/ This log will show you the time the query started and the time the query is ended (or cancelled).

Comment: This feature is now released in the latest live build (2019.2): https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/